# ceiling fan with receiver and only 1 red wire, how to I wire it?

Tags: ceiling-fan, installation

I have a ceiling fan which works on one switch through a receiver.  The remote stopped working, so only the light would switch on and off.  I inspected the fan and it works fine.
I pulled out the receiver and attached the fan wires, black to black, white to white and red to red.  The light worked with the original switch, but the fan only worked with the other switch which turns on a light outside.  Not sure how to wire it.  There are 2 black wires connected together an 2 white wires connected together and one single red wire.  Is it possible that the receiver for the remote was attached only to the red wire?

Comment: The receivers in the fans I have installed could only use a single hot input. They had two switched output hots, one for the fan and one for the light. So originally I would say the light and the fan were both fed by the red hot. These wireless remotes were designed for the case where there was only one switched hot which you would have if there was originally only wiring for light fixtures that were all controlled by the same switch.

Comment: Hi Laura, a photo always helps :-)